# Why does 'doit list' run for hours on a large dataset?

Tags: doit

I have a large number of files, 200k+, with a sub-task defined for each file.  When I run anything, even 'doit list', it takes 2-3 hours before doit responds.

I'd like to understand what it is doing meanwhile.

I have ran '`doit list' and 'doit --check_file_uptodate timestamp list'` and each ran for 2-3 hours.

I tried the later run as I assumed the time is spent in calculating md5 hashes for all these files.  It resulted in an error after 2.5 hours: ERROR: Invalid parameter: "list". Must be a command, task, or a target.

I have also tried adding the timestamp directive in the dodo.py like shown below, but had similar results.

```
DOIT_CONFIG = {'check_file_uptodate': 'timestamp'}
```

Comment: What did you expect? You have simply really huge number of files to check, 200k files in 3 hours means, 0.054 seconds to check one file.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky, that's horrible answer.  I expected to perform close to make.  First, if I want to get help, it doesn't need to check the files. It also doesn't need to check the files to list the targets.  Secondly, when I implement the same in tasks in Make, Make is able to stat the same files much much faster.  I am trying to understand why.

Comment: Make takes 15 minutes to get to execution while doit takes over an hour and half, on the same dataset.  So, again, I am just trying to understand why.

Comment: Just to add more information: doit used over 4GB of memory while Make used a little under 1GB.  In my runs, I was using 'doit -n 10', which seems to work and required over 44GB of memory.